# Clarification on behaviour of comparing invalid pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

I'm a bit confused about the language of the standard (N4868 to be specific). To my understanding, pointers are classified under
6.8.3 [basic.compound]:

> (3.1) — a pointer to an object or function (the pointer is said to point to the object or function), or

> (3.2) — a pointer past the end of an object (7.6.6), or

> (3.3) — the null pointer value for that type, or

> (3.4) — an invalid pointer value

Where an invalid pointer is further
elaborated in Note 2:

> [Note 2 : A pointer past the end of an object (7.6.6) is not considered to point to an unrelated object of the object’s
> type that might be located at that address. A pointer value becomes invalid when the storage it denotes reaches the
> end of its storage duration; see 6.7.5. — end note]

My first question is, under the next clause a pointer 'past the end of the array' is deemed to be valid. Am I to understand that this is exactly one past the end of the array or that all pointers past the end of the array are valid. The note above would have me believe that a pointer that does not point to an instantiated object is automatically invalid, since it is pointing to potentially unallocated memory. So perhaps only pointers immediately past the end of the array are valid?

> For purposes of pointer arithmetic (7.6.6) and comparison (7.6.9, 7.6.10), a pointer past the end of the
> last element of an array x of n elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical array
> element n of x and an object of type T that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array
> with one element of type T. The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined. Pointers to
> layout-compatible types shall have the same value representation and alignment requirements (6.7.6).

The reason for all of this is because the standard very clearly specifies what it considers to be defined pointer relational comparisons, indeed 7.6.9 [expr.rel] says:

> (4.1) — If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to
> the element with the higher subscript is required to compare greater.

> (4.2) — If two pointers point to different non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects of such
> members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member is required to compare greater provided
> the two members have the same access control (11.9), neither member is a subobject of zero size, and
> their class is not a union.

> (4.3) — Otherwise, neither pointer is required to compare greater than the other.

Which to me would suggest that if a pointer does not point to an array element or an object that has not reached the end of its lifetime, it is invalid. So, if I want to create a function that checks whether a pointer is within the bounds of an array i.e:

```
template<class Type>
bool is_bounded(Type* arr_first, Type* arr_last, Type* elem) {
    return (arr_first <= elem) && (elem < arr_last);
}
```

Would this be undefined behaviour if `elem` is not in the interval [`arr_first`, `arr_last`] since there is no guarantee `elem` points to anything? Which in turn invalidates the existence of this function since I can't guarantee its (expected) false results are defined?

P.S. I apologise in advance for the perhaps confusing wording of the question, I'll try my best to elaborate or clarify if anyone asks.

---

Edit: I would like to clarify why the details here matter to me (Thank you, everyone, for the help). I'm currently on a journey to learn how to write quality well defined containers and in my container iterators I wanted to do some debug-only checks to ensure a user doesn't accidentally invalidate the iterator. The problem arose when considering the operator+= overload of a contiguous iterator.

```
Container& operator+=(difference_type n) {
    assert(_check_valid(n));
    _ptr += n;
    return *this;
}
```

Here I had two options for `_check_valid(n)` either using `is_bounded(_first, _last, _curr + n)` where `_first`, `_last` and `_curr` are pointers to the first element of the array, one past the last element of the array and the pointer to the value stored by the iterator, respectively; or doing something along the lines of:

```
bool _check_valid(difference_type n) {
    difference_type size  = _last - _first;
    difference_type index = _curr - _first;

    return (index + n) >= 0 && (index + n) <= size;
}
```

Where the latter, as far as I can see, has no undefined behaviour assuming `_curr` is in the closed interval [`_first`, `_last`] (easier to enforce), whereas the former could become undefined if `n` is too large. However, I didn't want to over-engineer unnecessarily and would have much preferred a simpler function like `is_bounded`. Now I see that indeed the former is not the right way to go. Thank you.

Comment: the thing is, you should know how big your arrays are. If there's a mistake `valgrind` or some other checker might catch it. c++ won't hold your hand.

Comment: I fully understand that 'c++ won't hold my hand', I've been struck by this many times before, haha. I should've maybe stated why this is important to me. I'm currently working on learning how to write good well defined libraries and it is very common for containers to use pointers to define the bounds of arrays rather than a pointer to an element followed by an integral size type (simply works better with iterators). Hence, I would like to provide code that 'tries' to hold the user's hand a little bit by doing rudimentary error checking, but without the checks being undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I to understand that this is exactly one past the end of the array or that all pointers past the end of the array are valid.

Only a pointer *one*-past-the-array or *one*-past-the-object is valid (although you cannot dereference such a pointer). Pointers after that cannot be constructed, because pointer arithmetic has undefined behavior past this point.

> The note above would have me believe that a pointer that does not point to an instantiated object is automatically invalid, since it is pointing to potentially unallocated memory.

The pointer doesn't need to point to an actual object if it is the one-past-end pointer. However such a pointer cannot be dereferenced. The pointers to the array/object, including the one-past-the-end pointer become invalid as soon as the storage duration of the object/array ends.

> Which to me would suggest that if a pointer does not point to an array element or an object that has not reached the end of its lifetime, it is invalid.

The one-past-the-end pointers are considered a hypothetical element of the (hypothetical) array for the quoted clauses, see the note under the section referencing [basic.compound].

> Would this be undefined behaviour if elem is not in the interval [arr_first, arr_last] since there is no guarantee elem points to anything?

Assuming `arr_first` is the first element of an array and `arr_last` the last element of the array, your function has unspecified behavior if `elem` doesn't point into the range `arr_first` to `arr_last+1` inclusive.

This doesn't mean that it has undefined behavior, just that the return value of the function may be completely arbitrary.

However, trying to form e.g. a pointer `arr_last+2` to pass to the function already has undefined behavior itself, since pointer arithmetic is only defined as long as one stays within the bounds of the array (or one-past-the array).

> Which in turn invalidates the existence of this function since I can't guarantee its (expected) false results are defined?

The function as written is technically not useful, although I suppose it will work more or less as expected in practice most of the time. It is a much better approach to validate indices into the array, rather than pointers.

Comment: _one-past-the-array or one-past-the-object_ What is the difference?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer None as far as I can tell, except that I assume many readers wouldn't immediately realize that they are the same thing.